# Expected distance between 2 RVs and the origin

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, distance

I have the following question:

Let (X1,X2) be two independent standard normal random variables. Compute the expected distance between (X1,X2) and the origin.

I have already computed the joint pdf by using polar coordinates. After which, I am pretty much stuck. Can anyone show me the proper steps? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The "distance" from the origin is just the radial coordinate $R = \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}.$ So you just calculate the expected value of $R.$

$$
E[R] = E\left[\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2} \right] = \iint_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_1,x_2) \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} dx_1 dx_2. 
$$

The above expression is what you're trying to solve, so you can just convert that into polar coordinates and solve.

In case you have trouble solving the resulting integral after converting to polar coordinates, you can use the following trick:
$$
\int_a^b x^2 e^{-\lambda x^2} dx = \int_a^b \left(-\frac{d}{d \lambda} e^{- \lambda x^2} \right)dx = - \frac{d}{d \lambda} \int_a^b e^{-\lambda x^2} dx.
$$

Comment: thank you very much! Indeed, I was stuck at the integration part!